# Sublime Text 2: keep build panel open

Tags: sublimetext2

Is it possible to keep this panel open? Whenever I save, the window is hidden and I need to rebuild to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply select **`Tools → Build Results → Show Build Results`**. You can also select **`… → Next Result`** or **`… → Previous Result`** to move through recent builds.